Xcode keeps asking password prompt for swift-package-registry
I have one package located at swift package registry in Artifactory which is available through authorization with login and password. I try to build via Gitlab CI or locally and during resolve package graph it freezes due to Xcode asking prompt.
I tried to unlock_kecyhain from fastlane but it still freezes. Then I tried to add password for registry not with swift package-registry login --username $1 --password $2 but with manually adding password to keychain with permissions for Xcode to access this password security add-internet-password -a $1 -s <url> -r htps -w $2 -T /Applications/Xcode.app -T /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild. But this didn't work either. Also tried to swift package-registry login with options --disable-keychain and --enable-netrc but also did not help getting no prompt. Still getting prompt on CI and locally.
Can I somehow make it work without accessing every build machine and checking always allow for this password?

After some additional research turns out netrc doesn't work with Xcode UI (https://github.com/swiftlang/swift-package-manager/issues/6395). But when using with xcodebuild credentials can be fetched from netrc file.
Steps for using netrc with xcodebuild on CI:

swift package-registry --netrc login --username <login> --password <password> --no-confirm
If using directly xcodebuild you can add -packageAuthorizationProvider netrc or with fastlane you can add package_authorization_provider('netrc') to Gymfile and Scanfile.

Developers continue using keychain.
